# Send individual data from one thread to multiple threads in python using Queue

Tags: python, multithreading, queue

I want to share send data from multiple worker threads to one thread, have that thread process all the data received and send data to the multiple worker threads, where each thread receives different data.

I want all of the threads to run over a long time.

I kind of want to use queues and thought about a something like this:

```
from threading import Thread
import Queue
import time
import random

nr_of_workers = 3

class SyncData(Thread):

    def __init__(self, q_in, q_out):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.setDaemon(True)
        self.q_in = q_in
        self.q_out = q_out
        self.start()

    def run(self):
        for j in range(4):
            msg_list = []
            for i in range(nr_of_workers):
                msg_list.append( self.q_in.get() )
                self.q_in.task_done()
            for i in range(nr_of_workers):
                addr = msg_list[i][0]
                print "addr " , addr
                message = msg_list[i][1]
                message_out = "message from thread addr " + str(addr) + " " + message 
                self.q_out.put(( addr, message_out ))
            time.sleep(2.0)

class ThreadWorker(Thread):

    def __init__(self, q_in, q_out, addr):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.addr = addr
        self.q_in = q_in
        self.q_out = q_out
        self.setDaemon(True)
        self.start()


    def run(self):
        for j in range(4):
            self.q_out.put((self.addr, "hello from thread"))
            recv_msg = self.q_in.get()
            self.q_in.task_done()
            print recv_msg[1]


q_sync2workers = Queue.Queue()
q_workers2sync = Queue.Queue()

sync = SyncData(q_workers2sync, q_sync2workers)
threads = []
for i in range(nr_of_workers):
    threads.append(ThreadWorker(q_sync2workers, q_workers2sync, i))

while True:
    pass
```

where each ThreadWorker sends data over a queue, and receives data over a different queue. The only problem is that I want the SyncData object to send different data to different ThreadWorker, kind of address each part sent over the queue with an id, so that each ThreadWorker only gets the element in the queue specified for that specific ThreadWorker.

I do not really want to have one queue for each ThreadWorker because my real application will be adding and removing ThreadWorkers during runtime.

Any tips on good strategy, either with using Queues, or a more good-practice strategy?

Comment: What is your goal? Performance-boost or just running stuff in parallel? Are you aware of the `GIL` and that only c-calls with an unlocked GIL will benefit from real multithreading? What do you want to execute in parallel?

Comment: Not for performance-boost. My goal is to have multiple threads receiving data over sockets, and have one thread that processes the data received from all the socket threads. A "packet" resulting from the processed data should then be sent to each socket thread.

Comment: You can group a bunch of sockets in a single-thread by using `non-blocking` sockets and poll for receive. But to be back on topic I would go with a Queue in combination with a condition variable (which is triggered whenever a task is complete) Avoid sleeps when working with threading whenever possible. Events are the best way to go and to avoid time gaps between ready-and-being-processed.